# What is the "ScriptEngine" function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I just stumbled across this function in a certification exam and I have *never* heard about it before: [ScriptEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/efy5bay1(v=vs.94).aspx). I cannot Google (or Bing) it properly. The only useful page is the MSDN documentation from Microsoft. What is it used for?

Comment: From the documentation: "*Gets the name of the scripting language in use.*" Sounds like a bad certification exam if they are asking that. Have you heard about VBScript? Learn about that relic!

Comment: It was just one of many answers, and it was clearly a trick question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ScriptEngine" is not an engine. Its purpose is to display that thats the language in use.

```js
if ( window.ScriptEngine ) {
    console.log( window.ScriptEngine() ); // Output: "JScript"
}
```

Comment: It's a pretty useless function if I do say so myself. Lmao

Comment: In any browser other than IE, that would throw an error!

Comment: And that is the soul purpose? Do you know if it was created with extendability in mind, but the only implementation is JScript (and the implementation that implements the function ScriptEngine to output the name of the real scriptengine that runs under the hood).

Comment: @mslot - It's a completely useless function that's not part of javaScript at all, it's just something Microsoft implemented, God knows why!

Comment: I know that JScript is Microsoft's JavaScript engine that's powered by Windows Scripting Host. WSH also handles VBScript. I would suspect that it has some use in differentiating the JScript from VBScript somehow but don't ask me because I have no clue lol

Comment: @epascarello, I just thought of that! IE and vbscript!! Thanks for that.